# Log squared error accuracy justification: data mining competition

Tags: predictive-models, error

I was wondering what is the justification/rational for using the following error measure for judging accuracy instead of simply squared error?

[image]

Link to competition:
[Heritage Health](http://www.heritagehealthprize.com/c/hhp/Details/Evaluation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't defined the terms in the measure, but log squared error is useful when we expect all parties to perform extremely well. For example, in spam filtering, most modern filters get ~99.99% accuracy. Using squared error here is meaningless: Human's can't compare numbers that small intuitively. In contrast, using log squared error, we can clearly tell which filter is best.

Comment: The link contains the measures. They are predicted number of days (pi) and actual number of days (ai). Maybe that is it in this case as well. Thanks!